# Why is 'on' used in these expressions?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

1. Be strong on

   > I'm not too strong on organic chemistry, so I'm going to get a tutor this semester.
2. Be low on

   > We are running low on rice.
3. Be long on

   > He was short on patience, but long on a sense of his own worth.
4. Be short on

   > The president’s speech was long on colorful phrases but short on solutions.

I think that 'on' is used to convey the meaning of "regarding"

But why is it incorrect to say this way?

5. Be good on

   > I'm not very good on predictions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my (educated American) ear, sentences 2, 3, and 4 sound natural.  All of them have the form "short **on** <measurable quantity>" or "long **on** <measurable quantity>".

In sentence 1, "I'm not too strong **in** organic chemistry" would sound more natural to me.  This sentence is about a field of knowledge that you are either good **at**, or good **in**.

In sentence 5, "I'm not very good **with** predictions" would sound more natural to me.  Unfortunately, both "on" and "with" are unclear in this sentence:  Are you not very good at making accurate predictions, or are you not very good at making use of other people's predictions?  "I'm not very good **at** making predictions" would be both clear and natural.

Comment: To my Australian ear - I speak British - I almost agree with @Jasper. The exception is that I'd be pretty definite about preferring **at** for 1 and 5.

Comment: Educated British English:  Sentence 1 sounds fine.  With **at** is probably how I would produce it, and **in** sounds wrong ... which just goes to show that prepositions are *hard*.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Jasper about #1, so for me the question that underlies your question is what is it about **strong** and **good** (when they mean "skillful, capable") that  makes them unable to partner with **on** as **low** and **long** can?

> We are low on fuel.
>
> He is not very long on patience.  He is short on patience.

There, **on** introduces something for which we have a *supply*.  The supply can be ample or it can have become depleted.  We can "run out of" patience just as we can run out of fuel.

Skill and capability cannot become depleted.  We do not have a supply of skills that runs out when we use those skills.

Comment: The supply concept seems to be the important aspect. Maybe it is a callback to the physical nature, where you could literally be "sitting on" a pile of gold or something. "Short on patience" sounds familiar, but "long on" sounds strange. You can go "long on" and "short on" stocks in the stock market though.